# access subtotal - grouped by field should occur only once

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in access like below

```
select field1, column_date, sum(qty) from table
group by field1, column_date
union all
select field1, 'subtotal' as column_date, sum(qty) from table
group by field1
union all
select '', 'Grand Total' as column_date, sum(qty) from table
```

The above code displays output as below :

```
field1 | column_date | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
xyz    | 1 June 2012 | 23   | 36   | 343  | 45
xyz    | 2 June 2012 | 24   | 33   | 123  | 12
xyz    | 3 June 2012 | 55   | 25   | 21   | 45
**xyz    | subtotal    | 102  | 94   | 487  | 102**
abc    | 1 June 2012 | 15   | 23   | 46   | 21
abc    | 2 June 2012 | 24   | 81   | 25   | 21
abc    | 7 June 2012 | 33   | 25   | 43   | 21 
**abc    | subtotal    | 72   | 129  | 114  | 63**
etc......
```

But I don't want to repeat field1 values every time. I just want to display once at the top as below.

```
field1 | column_date | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 | qty4
xyz    | 1 June 2012 | 23   | 36   | 343  | 45
       | 2 June 2012 | 24   | 33   | 123  | 12
       | 3 June 2012 | 55   | 25   | 21   | 45
       | subtotal    | 102  | 94   | 487  | 102
abc    | 1 June 2012 | 15   | 23   | 46   | 21
       | 2 June 2012 | 24   | 81   | 25   | 21
       | 7 June 2012 | 33   | 25   | 43   | 21 
       | subtotal    | 72   | 129  | 114  | 63**
etc......
```

Is it possible either with query or with VBA code? Please help.

Comment: Where is this query ending up? Subtotals and totals are presentation level, not for queries.

Comment: at the end it has grand total ..I know but I don't know anything at presentation level...i just started learning sql and for now I'm try to finish my task at least with what I know.....Thanks for your reply BTW

Comment: What I am saying is that you will be showing these results to someone, how will you show the results? In a report, a form? It is at that point that you put in totals. You should not use queries for totals.

Comment: I don't know about reports or forms. I just export to excel and do some formatting before I send to someone. 
Before I was just doing in excel every thing. Just I moved on to access as it seems much quicker with query. I will soon get my hand on forms and reports also.

Comment: There is a subtotal wizard in Excel, it would be the best, I reckon : http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculating-subtotals-and-working-with-levels-in-excel-HA001109798.aspx Do not forget you can automate Excel from MS Access.

Comment: How comfortable are you with VBA code?  I have an idea I think might help you.

Comment: @ TexasTubbs..I'm new to VBA also.
@Hansup..oops.is it deleted by you? i don't have a copy of your code  so it seems I lost it. At least I could have tried on my own later based on your code.

Comment: user1449596, how is it coming along?  Are you progressing, or do you still need some help?

@HansUp Do you see any issues with my code example for what he is attempting to do?  I've seen your answers on other questions, and would value your input!

Comment: @user1449596 When you indicated the source data can include duplicate column_date values within each field1 group, I realized my SQL-only approach would not work, so I deleted that answer.

Comment: @TexasTubbs
Thanks a lot for your valuable answers in many questions.
As to this question, to be frank, I'm really confused with the code and I'm not able to modify it myself. I'm trying to learn more basics before I can try. In the meantime, if you have time, please modify your code for four quantity (qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4) and it should allow duplicate dates also. I will check and accept your answer once I see output...otherwise I will keep trying and hopefully will come back in 1 or 2 days and let you know..
BTW thanks to Hansup too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has expressed a beginner understanding of VBA, so for the others who may use this code, please keep that in mind when reading through and notice the comments in the code.

Please consider this VBA as a possible solution.  I have tested this in an access 2007 database.  I created a form with a button whose on_click event, calls this subroutine.

Once this executes, you can have the buttons on_click event make a call to a VBA module which exports the data contained in "tbl_output" to an excel spread sheet.

Below is a screen shot which shows proof of it working as requested:

[image: Proof of records with proper roll-up]

Here is the code that I came up which makes this possible.  This is my interpretation of how the end result can be achieved:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub QueryRollUp()

Dim db As Database
Dim rst_Input As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst_Output As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim tdfNew As TableDef
Dim tdfLoop As TableDef
Dim prpLoop As Property
Dim s_tdef As String
Dim s_CurrentRollUp As String
Dim s_CurrentField1 As String
Dim s_CurrentDate As String
Dim s_CurrentQty1 As Integer
Dim s_CurrentQty2 As Integer
Dim s_CurrentQty3 As Integer
Dim s_CurrentQty4 As Integer
Dim i As Integer

' If the subroutine is going to access parts of the database (tables, queries, etc.)
' you must have a representation of the database in the code.
' In this code, I use 'db' as that representation.
' VBA has a shortcut for defining the database that is currently open, and that is         'CurrentDB'.
' You can define an external database if necessary, but that goes beyond the scope of     this example.
' The below line sets the database code object 'db' equal to this database

Set db = CurrentDb

' The next step is to create a new table programaitcally for the output to go
' I choose to do this in code instead of building it in table designer
' because I want to ensure you get the correct tbl_Output that my code is
' expecting.  If you were desining a new module, and new how the correct table needed
' to be designed, you can omit everything between the hash marks

'#####################################################################################

' This current database.
' I like to use 'With' so I don't have to keep typing the name.
' I can just type .something and the code knows I really mean db.something
' Each 'With' must have an 'End With' to let the code know when you are no longer
' wanting it to assume you are using the short cut.

With db

'this loops trough all of the items in the table definitions
'the looping logic takes place between the % signs
'%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
For Each tdfLoop In .TableDefs
    ' Check the name of an item 'tdfLoop.Name' to see if it the
    ' same as "tbl_Output".
    If tdfLoop.Name = "tbl_Output" Then
        ' We are going to create this table later.
        ' If the table already exists, it will cause an error and
        ' the code will halt.  Deleting the table prevents the
        ' conflict.

        db.TableDefs.Delete "tbl_Output"

    End If

' This bit of code moves to the next item in the table definitions collection
' and then loops back and tests for tbl_Output again.
Next tdfLoop
'%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
End With

' Create a new TableDef object.
' This assigns the object "tbl_Output" to a variable so I can access it
' shorthand.  The variable is called 'tdfNew'
Set tdfNew = db.CreateTableDef("tbl_Output")

' Using the 'With' again, but this time is tdfNew, and not db that
' I am shortcutting.  Remember that there is an implied 'tdfNew'
' in front of each .Fields.Append an also .CreateField(...)

With tdfNew
' Create fields and append them to the new TableDef
' object. This must be done before appending the
' TableDef object to the TableDefs collection of the
' database.

' Each line here adds a new field to the table
' This is the code equivilent of designing a table
' in the graphical UI
.Fields.Append .CreateField("name", dbText)
.Fields.Append .CreateField("column_date", dbText)
.Fields.Append .CreateField("qty1", dbInteger)
.Fields.Append .CreateField("qty2", dbInteger)
.Fields.Append .CreateField("qty3", dbInteger)
.Fields.Append .CreateField("qty4", dbInteger)

' Append the new TableDef object to the database.
' The net effect of this is to create a new table
' within the database using the information above.
db.TableDefs.Append tdfNew

End With

'#####################################################################################
' Open rst_Output as a recordset tied to new 'tbl_Output' table\
' the .OpenRecordset creates an incode representation of a database table.
' All of the specified table columns are recreated, and populated.  If no
' specific columns are listed (such as in a query), then it defaults to all columns.

' When using the .OpenRecordset("table_name", [type]) method, there are several [types]
' you can choose.  The type you choose determines the way it opens in the code
' and what you can do with it.  The most flexible is dbOpenDynaset, but is generally     slower
' in performacne with huge amounts of data.  dbOpenTable is equivelant to opening the     table directly

Set rst_Output = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_Output", dbOpenTable)

' Create query string to pull data from the database.
' For readability I have split this process up on several lines.
' Each time a new line is needed you must add the
' new information to the information you already have
' This is accomplished by doing strSQL = strSQL & "..." on each line after the first
' If you just did strSQL = "..." for each line, you would overwrite what was there     before

strSQL = "select field1, column_date, sum(qty1) as Total1, sum(qty2) as Total2,     sum(qty3) as Total3, sum(qty4) as Total4 "
strSQL = strSQL & " from [table]"
strSQL = strSQL & " group by field1, column_date"
strSQL = strSQL & " union all"
strSQL = strSQL & " select field1, 'subtotal' as column_date, sum(qty1) as Total1, sum(qty2) as Total2, sum(qty3) as Total3, sum(qty4) as Total4 "
strSQL = strSQL & " from [table]"
strSQL = strSQL & " group by field1"
strSQL = strSQL & " union all"
strSQL = strSQL & " select '', 'Grand Total' as column_date, sum(qty1) as Total1,     sum(qty2) as Total2, sum(qty3) as Total3, sum(qty4) as Total4 "
strSQL = strSQL & " from [table]"
strSQL = strSQL & " order by field1 desc, column_date asc"

' After the above code, your whole query is now stored in strSQL.

' Execute query and populate rst_Input with the result set.
' Ensure full recordset has been retrieved before continuing.
' This becomes more important the larger the result set is.
' The dbOpenSnapshot type is like creating a virtual image
' of the data just queried.  Like a photo, it can't be changed,
' only looked at.  Since we only want to read the data, this
' is a more optimal type of OpenRecordset than a dynaset.
' All of the contents are moved into rst_Input.

Set rst_Input = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

' Now we are going to manipulate the information
' returned by the query as it is stored inside the
' rst_Input variable.
With rst_Input
' The .MoveLast forces the recordset to go the very last
' record of the returned query.  Omitting this step could
' result in the code starting before all of the data is
' returned by the query.
' .MoveFirst returns to the top of the list once all data
' is returned

.MoveLast
.MoveFirst

' Begin process of evaluating query results
' This will keep looping until the current record is the
' end of the returned data.
Do Until .EOF

    ' Use 'i' as the index of the current roll-up value.
    ' Default this value to 1 for the first each time the field1 value changes.
    ' The example  has 'xyz' and 'abc'.
    i = 1

    ' Move the data from the query which is stored in
    ' the rst_Input from the fields to variables
    s_CurrentRollUp = .Fields("field1").Value
    s_CurrentField1 = .Fields("field1").Value
    s_CurrentDate = .Fields("column_date").Value
    s_CurrentQty1 = .Fields("total1").Value
    s_CurrentQty2 = .Fields("total2").Value
    s_CurrentQty3 = .Fields("total3").Value
    s_CurrentQty4 = .Fields("total4").Value

    ' While working with all field1 values (i.e. 'xyz') values which are the same
    ' the following 'Do While' loop will execute.
    Do While s_CurrentRollUp = s_CurrentField1
        ' If this is the firs time the values match do everything betwen the '#' marks
        If i = 1 Then
        '#############################################

            ' If the CurrentDate value is not a real date
            ' do the following
            If s_CurrentDate = "Grand Total" Then

                With rst_Output

                    ' .AddNew tells the recordset we are adding a new record
                    .AddNew

                    ' Here we use a '!' (pronounced 'bang') to let VBA know
                    ' we are accessing members of a collection, and not a
                    ' method of doing something with rst_Output.
                    !column_date = s_CurrentDate
                    !qty1 = s_CurrentQty1
                    !qty2 = s_CurrentQty2
                    !qty3 = s_CurrentQty3
                    !qty4 = s_CurrentQty4

                    ' .Update tells the recordset we are done adding, and to save it
                    .Update
                End With

            ' If the CurrentDate value is a real date
            ' do the following
            Else
                With rst_Output
                    .AddNew

                    !Name = s_CurrentField1
                    !column_date = s_CurrentDate
                    !qty1 = s_CurrentQty1
                    !qty2 = s_CurrentQty2
                    !qty3 = s_CurrentQty3
                    !qty4 = s_CurrentQty4
                    .Update
                End With
            End If
            ' set index to optimistically reflect second record of rollup
            ' Values above '1' tell the logic that we are still using the
            ' same field1 ('xyz') value, but are no longer on the first
            ' occurance of the 'xyz' value.
            i = i + 1

            ' move to the next record of the input recordset
            .MoveNext

            'test if last move is the end of file
            If .EOF Then
                'exit sub if the end of file has been reached.
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' get next field1 value to test in the do while exit condition
            If IsNull(.Fields("field1").Value) Then
                s_CurrentField1 = " "
            Else
                s_CurrentField1 = .Fields("field1").Value
            End If

        '#############################################
        ' If there is another record with the same field1 value (i.e. 'xyz'
        ' then do the following logic.
        ' This will replace the 'xyz' with an empty value so it does not
        ' show up in the tbl_Output table
        ElseIf i > 1 Then

            ' Move the data from the query which is stored in
            ' the rst_Input from the fields to variables
            s_CurrentField1 = " "
            s_CurrentDate = .Fields("column_date").Value
            s_CurrentQty1 = .Fields("total1").Value
            s_CurrentQty2 = .Fields("total2").Value
            s_CurrentQty3 = .Fields("total3").Value
            s_CurrentQty4 = .Fields("total4").Value

            With rst_Output
                .AddNew
                !Name = s_CurrentField1
                !column_date = s_CurrentDate
                !qty1 = s_CurrentQty1
                !qty2 = s_CurrentQty2
                !qty3 = s_CurrentQty3
                !qty4 = s_CurrentQty4
                .Update
            End With

            ' Set index to optimistically reflect second record of rollup
            i = i + 1

            ' Move to the next record of the input recordset
            .MoveNext

            ' Get next field1 value to test in the do while exit condition
            ' The IsNull makes sure that in the event that no information
            ' exists in the field1 column of the table, it is replaced with
            ' a " " character to avoid an invalid use of NULL in the variable
            If IsNull(.Fields("field1").Value) Then
                s_CurrentField1 = " "
            Else
                s_CurrentField1 = .Fields("field1").Value
            End If

        End If

    Loop  'do while

Loop 'do until

End With

' Now that everything has finished, it's proper coding technique
' to release all of the resources consumed by our data containing
' variables.
db.Close
rst_Output.Close
rst_Input.Close
Set db = Nothing
Set rst_Output = Nothing
Set rst_Input = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks TexasTubbs. 
I edited my original post. Actually, I have four quantity as above.
I'm not sure how I can adjust your code for all the four quantity.
I will try and let you know.

Comment: if you get stuck, let me know.  I can alter my code to do what you need to if necessary.

Comment: Also, I see that you have 5 questions without an accepted answer.  Are any of those still a pain point for you?  I can try to answer some of them if you let me know which ones you still require assistance with.

Comment: wow! you are great!...In fact I have been long time looking for solution to my problem in question - asp-querystring-between-two-number


As to question in this page, yeah I'll try and let you know the outcome...Of course it needs a lot of time for me...but will update you ..again thanks a lot

Comment: For this question, you should only have to edit the strSQL lines by first adding new s_CurrentQty variables in the DIM section.  Then add the additional query information for the new qty columns. Next then add the addtional .fields.append .creatfield("qtyX") lines, replacing qtyX with the name of the columns your query is pulling back.

Then do your new variable assignments following my examples.  That should be all you need to do!

Comment: You should include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations section of the module, then run `Debug->Compile` from the VBE main menu.  After dealing with the compiler's complaint about `tdfloop`, fixed anything else the compiler complains about.  `Option Explicit` is important for VBA code hygiene.  Never code without it.

Comment: Your recordsets must be DAO rather than ADO recordsets.  Declare them explicitly as such: `Dim rst_Input As DAO.Recordset`  That will avoid trouble if the project includes a reference for ActiveX Data Objects and the priority of that reference is higher than the DAO reference.  An *ADO* recordset is not compatible with `db.OpenRecordset`.

Comment: Consider `dbAppendOnly` as the option with `db.OpenRecordset` for `rst_Output`.  You will only be adding rows to `tbl_Output`, and `dbAppendOnly` may give you significantly faster performance.  Also consider `dbOpenSnapshot` instead of `dbOpenDynaset` for `rst_Input`; I don't see why you would need `dbOpenDynaset` there.

Comment: I don't understand the reason to delete `tbl_Output` each time, then recreate it from scratch.  If you just want to ensure it's empty, simply execute `DELETE FROM tbl_Output;`

Comment: The OP changed the target after you submitted this answer.  You offered guidance to adapt your code to handle the qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4 fields.  However OP is new to VBA and may find that to be an overwhelming task.  OP may not be able to use your code unless you revise it for him.

Comment: @HansUp, thank you for the feedback, I'll do revisions and annotate it with commentary to explain why i'm doing things, and why I felt it was necessary.

Comment: I admire your generosity and dedication on this one.  Cheers.